# A question about continuous functions (Proof)

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove  $f(x)=\frac{3}{2-x}$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

Let $a∈(0,1)$.

$|f(x)-f(a)|=|\frac{3}{2-x}-\frac{3}{2-a}|=|\frac{3(x-a)}{(2-x)(2-a)}|<3|x-a|=ε$

$a=x-\frac{ε}{3}$, then $3|x-a|=ε$ and $δ=\frac{ε}{3}$

$|\frac{3(x-a)}{(2-x)(2-a)}|<δ<ε$

Is this okay to prove $f(x)$  is continuous on $(0,1)$ , or am I missing something?

Edit: Forgot to mention that $ε>0$ and $δ>0$.

Comment: You've done a good chunk of the work and almost finished but in order to prove continuity you want to show that, given an $\epsilon$ there is not just one "x" but a neighbhorhood of "a" such that for every x in this neighborhood we have $|f(x)-f(a)|\leq \epsilon$. For the equality you wrote you showed there is one x, the one that satisfies $x-\epsilon/3=a$, but notice that if $y$ satisfies $|y-a|\leq \epsilon/3$ then what you wrote is also true for $y$ and that is the neighborhood you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous functions at $a$ and if $h(a)\neq 0$ then $f(x)=g(x)/h(x)$ is continuous at $a$.